# How to use case Statement in Where Clause in SQLserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need my query to check certain conditions based on the Customer's Status

Sample Data:

> ```
> Table  A
>     A_ID Customer_ID  Department  Feild  Case1 Case2 
>      1       101           X       A      FX1   Zx1
>      2       102           Y       B      FX2   ZX2
>      3       103           Z       C      FX3   ZX3
> ```

```
  Table  B ---- 
        B_ID      Customer_ID   Status  Feild  Match_Feild   Case1  Case2 
         1            101         C      Null      A          FX1    ZX1
         2            101       Manual    A        AX         FX0    ZX0
```

in my case if the status is manual then in the where condition i need to check with Feild alone
 else i need to check with other two conditions

> where 
>      case when Status ='Manual' then a.feild = b.feild
>        else 
>        a.Case1 = b.Case1
>          and 
>        a.Case2 = B.case2
>     end.

I am not sure how to put this in my query

Comment: What do you mean by NULL? Do you want remaining records or not

Comment: Is `Feild` supposed to be `Field`?

Comment: Of Status, Case1 and Case2, which columns are nullable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    where (Status = 'Manual' and a.feild = b.feild ) 
          OR 
          (Status<> 'Manual' AND a.Case1 = b.Case1 and a.Case2 = B.case2)
```

Comment: OR 1=1 will always count the condition as a success.